# runtimeAnimationController hash not found in animationClips

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that tells me which animation clip a runtimeAnimationController is currently playing for a character.

I'm using this script without any problems on some characters, but now I have one character where the hash of the current animation is not found in the list of animation clips.

I'm clueless what the cause of this problem might be.

I thought my code was absolutely fool safe.
When I create a breakpoint in Visual Studio and inspect the list of animation clips, I can see that the currently playing hash is really not among the list.

The currently playing animation's hash is also not 0, and it does change when the animation controller plays a different animation.

Does anybody see why the condition might occur where the hash is not found?

I mean when an animation is playing, this animation HAS to be in the list animation clips, right?

Thank you very much for the help!

```
private void pTellAnim()
{

    AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = _animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    int iCurrentAnimationHash = stateInfo.shortNameHash;

    foreach (AnimationClip nClip in _animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
    {
        int iHash = Animator.StringToHash(nClip.name);
        if (iHash == iCurrentAnimationHash)
        {
            Debug.Log("Currently playing " + nClip.name + "\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("Clip not found for hash " + iCurrentAnimationHash.ToString() + "!!!!\n");
}
```

Comment: You're only using layer 0 for your argument in `GetCurrentAnimnatorStateInfo(0)`.  Have you tried checking `_animator.layerCount` and making sure there's only one?

Comment: @Foggzie _animator.layerCount returns 1.

Comment: Alright, good to know.  Is there any reason you're using `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo` instead of [`GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo.html)?  You're comparing the hash of state info to the hashes of clips.  With what I assume you're trying to do, it seems like you should be using the later function, and checking the array of [`AnimatorClipInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorClipInfo.html) objects it returns.  Those will each have a `.clip` property.

Comment: @Foggzie Thank you. Your approach works fine for me. I found my approach in an old Unity post, I guess your approach didn't exist back then. Perhaps you could make your comment the answer?

Comment: @Foggzie I believe the problem is that the animation is not a "standalone" animation but still attached to a mesh / rig. Do you think I should post a bug report, or is my approach not of use anymore anyways?

Comment: Good idea! Sometimes I ramble too much in the comments :P  And I wouldn't report a bug; I don't think it's expected behavior for state info hashes to line up with clip hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing the hash of `AnimatorStateInfo` to the hashes of clips. You should instead use [`_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo.html), and check the array of [`AnimatorClipInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorClipInfo.html) objects it returns. Those will each have a `.clip` property.